# Summing attribute of feature in network along route using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

In the walking network that a friend and I are creating, we want to calculate an overall safety rating for each route. Each segment of our walking network has a certain safety value. We have calculated a "total safety" rating of each segment by multiplying the length of the segment by the safety value of the segment (1 to 5). When creating walking routes using Network Analyst, we want to be given the sum of all the "total safety" ratings for all the segments along the route. Using this, we can normalize this value by the total distance, giving us an overall safety value for the entire route.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [accumulations tab](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Finding_the_best_route) in your network properties.  This will record an attribute that sums the scores for each of the segments traversed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a **Pedestrian Level of Service (PLOS)** Index

http://www.thefreelibrary.com/A+data+model+and+internet+GIS+framework+for+safe+routes+to+school-a0214605855

probably over-complex for your model but an interesting way to create an index based on some rules.